# Wordpress redirect rules in WP-engine for wp-admin

Tags: wordpress, wpengine

I have my WordPress site hosted in ***Wp-Engine***. The Url for the site is `https://www.example.com/blogs.` I have another AEM site at `https://www.example.com`. I have the following Web Rules in Wp-Engine for redirection.

```
1. Internal rewrite /blogs/(.*) /$1

2. Permanent redirect (301 status code) `/blogs https://www.example.com/blogs`
```

Now I have the following issues.

1. I am not able to access `https://www.example.com/blogs/wp-admin` directly. It is going to `https://www.example.com/404.html`. But I can access `https://www.example.com/blogs/edit.php` or `https://www.example.com/blogs/plugins.php`
2. When I perform a search on Posts or Users, I am redirected to `https://www.example.com/wp-admin/edit.php?s=dummy&post_status=all&post_type=post&action=-1&m=0&cat=0&layout=63bff7d64f656&paged=1&action2=-1`

Note there are no `/blogs` added, so it is looking into the AEM site for the page, and as it is not there, it is again a 404 page.

I have added the following rule, but it is also not working.

```
Permanent redirect (301 status code) /wp-admin/(.*) http://www.example.com/blogs/$1
```

It would be very helpful if someone could point me in the right direction.

Update: It seems like the issue is when there is a query string in the URI. There is a 302 redirect, which cuts the `blogs` part from the URL